# How do you position a custom search box in the main menu?

Tags: routes, search

I'm using the Drupal 7 Mayo theme for my site. The theme comes with a search box that you can place in the header but no where else, so I made a custom search box block, which I would like to place to the right of the main menu bar, which has a horizontal list of dropdown menu links. When I try to move the search block to the main menu, however, it either pushes the links to a line below or appears on a line below the links depending on how I set the weight. I can't get them to match up. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

[Menu Inject Block](https://drupal.org/project/menu_inject_block) module was built exactly for the same purpose.

> This module allows you to inject blocks as menu items. It facilitates easier use of JavaScript based dropdowns and panel like navigation. Most users employ this module to create dropdown panels using other modules to handle the dropdowns and this module to inject the blocks as needed.

To use this module:

1. Enable the module
2. Create or Edit your menu item (/admin/build/menu)
3. Enter in  for the Path
4. Give your menu item a Title
5. Select a Block from the "BLOCK TO INJECT:" drop down (in your case the search block).
6. Save your menu item

You don't need to create a separate search block in case you use the module. You can place the default search block that Drupal provides, into step 5 mentioned above.